# xdt transforms for configuration files other than web.config

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xdt-transform

I've been looking into [xdt transforms for visual studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) and they seem quite neat for keeping track of environment changes, but all it mentions is for applying it to web.config. I'm working on a sitecore project which has other configuration files that need to be adjusted, and none of those show the option of "Add Config Transforms".

How can i add xdt transforms for other xml/configuration files in a project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). Scott Hanselman has a blog post about it with examples [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx).

Comment: You can use the nuget package also here https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/2.5.15